# inner content of jquery does-not resize when popup is resized

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

[image]

When ever I try to resize the jquery popup using the jquery resizable function. but the inner height of the content page of the popup does not resize. any ideas how to resize the height of the inner content.

Comment: The content that is not resizing should have width in percentage. like `100%` and for spacing from border use css `margin` or `padding`

Comment: thanks imdad for the reply i can adjust width of inner content but how to adjust the height of the inner content as i have made width="100%" and height="100%" kindly look at the new image i just pasted

Comment: Height is getting resized correctly. You can see the height of inner content is same as the dialog's inner height. You have to hide other divs otherwise the scrollbar will appear

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor the content div's, i've set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yoeri/CR3uU/) to do so

Anchoring is achieved by using absolute positioning with both top, bottom and left, right

Answer (score 0):

You can use resize event for your popup and set width and height of your div:

```
$("#popup").resize(function() {

});
```